# I am trying to write a basic chess engine in Javascript. The board is an array of arrays. Why cant I get the piece to move?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a chess engine in javascript. So far I have the initial set up where the pieces are placed and empty squares are marked with a '#'. When I change the square where the piece moved from to a '#', there is no issue. My issue comes in when I try to place the piece at its new position. It inserts the new piece name at multiple at the same index in multiple rows. I have a functions that return its initial position and the move function is passed the location of where the piece needs to end up . Here is my what the board looks like from the start, my code, and after I call the move function

```
[ [ 'bR1', 'bK1', 'bB1', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB2', 'bK2', 'bR2' ],
  [ 'ba7', 'bb7', 'bc7', 'bd7', 'be7', 'bf7', 'bg7', 'bh7' ],
  [ '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' ],
  [ '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' ],
  [ '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' ],
  [ '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' ],
  [ 'wa2', 'wb2', 'wc2', 'wd2', 'we2', 'wf2', 'wg2', 'wh2' ],
  [ 'wR2', 'wK2', 'wB2', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB1', 'wK2', 'wR1' ] ]

function findPiece(piece) {
    var i, j;
    let retArray = [];
    outer:
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {    
            if (board[i][j] == piece)
                break outer;
        }    
    }
    if (i == 8 && j == 8)
        return null;
    else
    {
        retArray.push(i);
        retArray.push(j);
        return retArray;
    }
};

function move(piece, square) {
    var piecePosition = findPiece(piece);
    var tmp = board[piecePosition[0]][piecePosition[1]];
    board[piecePosition[0]][piecePosition[1]] = board[square[0]][square[1]];
    board[square[0]][square[1]] = tmp;
    console.log(board)
};

move("we2", [4, 4]); 

after move called:
[ [ 'bR1', 'bK1', 'bB1', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB2', 'bK2', 'bR2' ],
  [ 'ba7', 'bb7', 'bc7', 'bd7', 'be7', 'bf7', 'bg7', 'bh7' ],
  [ '#', '#', '#', '#', 'we2', '#', '#', '#' ],
  [ '#', '#', '#', '#', 'we2', '#', '#', '#' ],
  [ '#', '#', '#', '#', 'we2', '#', '#', '#' ],
  [ '#', '#', '#', '#', 'we2', '#', '#', '#' ],
  [ 'wa2', 'wb2', 'wc2', 'wd2', '#', 'wf2', 'wg2', 'wh2' ],
  [ 'wR2', 'wK2', 'wB2', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB1', 'wK2', 'wR1' ] ]
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the way I am referencing the values in the array with the move function?

Comment: move ignores the case when find returns null.

Comment: Okay thank you I will add that and see if it changes anything

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you sure this is the right code? Usually the problem is that the board was initialized with the inner `#` rows all being the same array object, so they're aliases. Please share a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, ideally as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: find isnt returning null in this case, it is a valid piece and I am still getting the same result.  Any ideas??

Comment: Ggloren thats exactly what it is thank you so much

Comment: No problem, glad you found the issue.

Comment: You have two white knights with the same key. Probably not the problem since you aren't moving it, but you might want to fix it anyway.